# Fetching data in form of radio button format for quiz game in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, radio-button

I have stored data in database statically. Its having 5 col One for question and 4 col. for answers. Basically its a quiz game format. Now I want to fetch data from database in the form of radio button for that 4 col. How to implement that method. Currently i am fetching in normal text mode.

Here is the code

```
 <?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","QuizQuestions");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";

$sql = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 FROM Questions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>Question: " . $row["Question"]. "<br>";
    echo " A) " . $row["Answer1"]. "<br>";
    echo " B) " . $row["Answer2"]. "<br>";
    echo " C) " . $row["Answer3"]. "<br>";
    echo " D) " . $row["Answer4"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to make the answers into radio buttons. You can achieve this by doing this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>Question: " . $row["Question"]. "<br>";
    echo ' A) <input type="radio" value="'.$row["Answer1"].'">'.$row["Answer1"].'<br>';
    echo ' B) <input type="radio" value="'.$row["Answer2"].'">'.$row["Answer2"].'<br>';
    echo ' C) <input type="radio" value="'.$row["Answer3"].'">'.$row["Answer3"].'<br>';
    echo ' D) <input type="radio" value="'.$row["Answer4"].'">'.$row["Answer4"].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it's showing in the form of dropdown list not in radio buttons

Comment: thanku it's working but there is one problem..problem is that i am fetching more than 1 question (ex. 5 question at a time) so it's selecting only one from all the 5 questions

Comment: Upvote this as the answer ;) Make a new question about that problem and I can look at that aswell

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly.
and if your database field contain html code for radio button then u need to:

Use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

and [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Replace the following line..

```
 echo " A) " . $row["Answer1"]."<br>";
```

With

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row["Answer1"]));
```

else use simple php code to show front end

```
<input type='radio' name="ans" value="1" > <?php echo $row["Answer1"]; ?>
<input type='radio' name="ans" value="2" > <?php echo $row["Answer2"]; ?>

<input type='radio' name="ans" value="3" > <?php echo $row["Answer3"]; ?>
<input type='radio' name="ans" value="4" > <?php echo $row["Answer4"]; ?>
```

after that check value and validate ans on post

Answer (score 0):

why you dont try select than radio? but here's what you're looking for if i'm not mistaken

```
<input type="radio" name="'.$row["Answer1"].'" value="'.$row["Answer1"].'" />
then just validate in your javascript if the radio button has a value make it checked.
```